# Force user scroll the PDF to bottom to enable checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf, scroll

I need display a user guide in pdf format（more than 1 pages）, user have to read all the content, then only can check the checkbox.Below is my aspx code:

**ASPX:**

```
<iframe id="myIframe" runat="server" style="position: absolute; width: 500px; display: block; overflow: scroll;" src="../../Sample.pdf">
</iframe>
```

I am using the following javascript to handle scroll,but that is work for parent windows only, not work for iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(function() {
           var $win = $(window);
           $win.scroll(function() {
               if ($win.scrollTop() == 0)
                   alert('Scrolled to Page Top');
               else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
                   alert('Scrolled to Page Bottom');
               }
           });
       });
</script>
```

How do I solve this? or have another better approach? Thanks

Comment: here's a howto for your needs: http://shanelabs.com/blog/2012/02/21/getting-the-scrolltop-of-an-iframe-always-returning-0/

Comment: @gulty Thanks for your reply,but I'm not very understand the code. I'm newbie. Can you teach me how to do that? thanks

Comment: it is very well explained in the code. hes talking about the same thing you want to archieve. scrolling down inside an iframe and if it's been scrolled down allow to check the terms and conditions checkbox. just read the post and you will understand.

Comment: That is not work if my content is PDF.

Comment: Can you found anyhelp? please help me if you have done. Thanks